# Spring Boot WebSecurityConfig LogoutSuccessURL with invalidSessionUrl

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security, web-applications

I am working on a spring boot project and WebSecurityConfig for session control. The issue is that when the session expires, i am being redirected to `/?sessionexpired` when my expectation is that it should redirect o `/?expiredsession`. Also when user logout the page is redirected to `/?sessionexpired` and not `/?logout`.

My config is as follow

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/thirdparty/**", "/webjars/**", "/sessionerror").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .failureUrl("/?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")) // override default of only allowing POST for logout so we can use a GET
                .deleteCookies("remove")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/?expiredsession")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
                .and()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/?sessionexpired");
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i eventually figured it out. It is redirecting to `/?sessionexpired` because on logout i am invalidatingSession by setting it to true. I should set it to false and then use `.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")` to invalidate the session. This way it will redirect properly.